# expected a class or namespace, when using "c++ enum class" in objective-c code

Tags: c++, objective-c, objective-c++

Can anybody help me with such problem. I have definition in c++ header file.

```
enum class PixelFormat {
      ARGB32,
      RGB32
}
```

And when i'd like to do something like this in the objective-c .mm source file:

```
PixelFormat x = PixelFormat::ARGB32;
```

I get compilation error "expected a class or namespace" in OS X, by the way in Windows this example successfully compiles.

Solved problem by calling external code from C++. But still have one question, is it possible to do `PixelFormat x = PixelFormat::ARGB32;` in objective-c code?

Comment: This type of enum needs c++11 to compile. did you compile with `-std=c++11`?

Comment: @ArnonZilca, Yep, i did.

Comment: Don't know much about `c++` - `objective-c` connection, but this compiles wonderfully on my gcc (when compiled with enabled c++11).

Comment: What if you tried just: `PixelFormat x;` in your objective-c. or use an `enum` and not an `enum class`. try to see if you can narrow it down.

Comment: @ArnonZilca, when i am trying just `PixelFormat x;` it works fine, i've got error when i'm trying to get value `PixelFormat::ARGB32`.

Comment: And what happens if you try: `PixelFormat x = ARGB32;` or make `PixelFormat` just an `enum` rather than an `enum class`?

Comment: @ArnonZilca, `PixelFormat x = ARGB32` ---> use of undeclared identifier 'ARGB32' .
_just an enum rather than an enum class_ ---> the same error

Comment: @ArnonZilca, mmm, `PixelFormat x = PixelFormat::ARGB32;` works fine in .cpp class, but i got an error when i'm using this code in .mm src file (in objective-c class).

Comment: Works for me with `.mm` extension. is `PixelFormat` defined in a `.h` file that included directly or indirectly by `.m` file?

Comment: @BryanChen, `PixelFormat` defined in .h file that included directly